# How to add values left of the horizontal bar chart in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have implemented horizontal barChart successfully by using MPAndroidChart library. here is my code,

```
HorizontalBarChart barChart = (HorizontalBarChart)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);

                BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
                barChart.setData(data);
                barChart.invalidate();
                barChart.setDescription("");  // Hide the description
                barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
                barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
                barChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
                barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                barChart.setDrawBorders(false);
                barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
                barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);

                barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
                barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
                barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
                barChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);

                barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
                barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
                //YAxis
                YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setEnabled(false);

                barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
                barChart.setClickable(false);
                barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
      private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(1110f, 0);
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(4075f, 1);
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(6080f, 2);
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(6563f, 3);
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(6000f, 4);
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "");
        barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("1");
        xAxis.add("2");
        xAxis.add("3");
        xAxis.add("4");
        xAxis.add("5");
        return xAxis;
    }
```

but my question is, i want to be add red circle rated values with icon in barChart like the image below,

[image]